# How to separate legacy table from Django built-in models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a legacy table that I would like to use in a database-first way. To achieve this, I executed the following command in my Django project directory:

`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

However, I do not want to modify this database or add any of the Django core models. Instead, I would like to set a local SQLite database for all built-in models, including Auth, User, and Group.

In my settings.py file, I have configured two databases as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'admin.db'),
    },
    'legacy': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blahblah',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        }
    },
}
```

I understand that there is an option for automatic database routing, but I am unsure what else I need to configure to separate these databases and ensure that the separation works in the Django admin panel.
Can you please provide guidance on how to accomplish this? Thank you in advance.